# Best way to select column where not in table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a unique column, "X".

I would like to pass a list to a stored procedure using a table value pair of X, and I would like back a list of all the X's that do not exist in the table.

What is the most efficient way to do this in SQL Server?

EDIT:

I've come up with this. Not sure how efficient it is:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList_TBLType AS TABLE (s NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].ReturnProductsNotExisting
(
    @CatalogIdList StringList_TBLType READONLY  
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT s FROM @CatalogIdList
    WHERE s NOT IN (SELECT CatalogId from Products)
END
```

Comment: I should add that the list of X's I am passing in is 10 000 items per execution of the stored procedure

Comment: What is "table value pair"? Do you mean "table valued parameter" with a single column?

Comment: Sorry, I did mean table valued parameter with a single column

Comment: I've come up with this. Not sure if it is the most efficient way.

Comment: If `CatalogId` in `Products` is not nullable it should be as efficient as any other (and give the same plan as `NOT EXISTS`) If you are passing a large number of rows then you could add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` so it takes account of the number of rows actually contained in the TVP.